# Address and return values of cin

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner, and I was told that in codes like

```
int a;  
if(cin>>a);
```

if the input is successful, cin will yield true and vice versa.
But when I want to output the bool value,

```
cout<<boolalpha<<(cin>>a)<<endl;
```

it gives an address:

```
0x6fcc41e8
```

I was also told that `cin` is an object, but

```
cout<<&cin<<endl;
```

gives value

```
0x6fcc41e0
```

which is different by 8.
a. Why the first `cout` gives a address rather than a bool value?
b. Why two `cout` give different address?
Thanks.

Comment: What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Someone misled you.  `cin` is an `istream` and the `>>` operator returns an `istream &`.   See details [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cin >> a` returns the stream object `cin`.

Until C++11, `std::istream` had a conversion function `operator void*() const;`, meaning that there was an implicit conversion from `std::istream` to `void*`.  The actual value of the pointer was meaningless, except that a null value meant a failure had occurred and a non-null value meant success.  This allowed things like `if (cin >> a)` to work correctly.

It appears you're using a pre-C++11 compiler or compiler settings, so that when you try to output it you get that meaningless `void*` value.

In C++11 and later, `std::istream` instead has a conversion function `explicit bool() const;`, meaning that there is a valid conversion from `std::istream` to `bool`, but only where explicitly requested.  An `if` or `while` counts as explicitly requesting a conversion to `bool`, but

```
cout<<boolalpha<<(cin>>a)<<endl;
```

does not, so your code would not compile in C++11 and later.  You would need

```
cout << boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(cin>>a) << endl;
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

First, observe that the result of `cin >> a` is a reference to an istream object.

> Why the first cout gives a address rather than a bool value?

That is because an istream object must be "implictly convertible to bool" so that the expression can be used in the condition of an `if` statement. Before C++11, compilers typically allowed istream to be converted to `void *`. When you pass the result of `cin >> a` to cout via the `<<` operator, it chooses this conversion to `void *` and prints whatever address is returned.

> Why two cout give different address?

That is because the compiler chose to return some address that is not `&cin` when it converts to `void *`. (Remember that the precise value of the conversion to `void *` is irrelevant; it is only relevant whether the value is or is not `NULL`.)

Answer (score -1):

`boolalpha()` returns an `ios_base&` not bool
use instead:

```
cout << (bool)(cin >> x) << endl;
```

Comment: Your answer is misguided. The point of `boolalpha` is to print "true" and "false" instead of 1 and 0 when a `bool` is written to an `ostream`. More here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha What OP really wants to do, preserving the C-style cast, is `cout << boolalpha << (bool)(cin>>a) << endl;`