# C++ detect empty value

Tags: c++, double, cin

If the sales manager does not enter any sales amounts, the program should display the “Invalid Input”
message.

```
    double sales = 0.0;
    double totSales = 0.0;
    double aveSales = 0.0;
    int ctr = 0;
    
    cout << "Please enter sales amount: \n";

    for (int x = 0; x >= 0; x++){
        cout << ">>";
        cin >> sales;
        if (sales > 0){
            totSales += sales;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (sales == 0){
            cout << "Invalid input.\n\n";
            x = x - 1;
        }
        else{
            ctr = x;
            x = -2;
        }
    }
    aveSales = totSales / ctr;
    cout << "Average Sales: " << aveSales << endl;
```

I already tried length, size, empty, fail and null. None of them work.

```
else if (sales == 0 || this where I added the second condition for empty input){
            cout << "Invalid input.\n\n";
            x = x - 1;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `any sales amounts`? Do you mean invalid input like `3857ksnd`?

Comment: The
program will use a counter to keep track of the number of sales amounts entered and an
accumulator to total the sales amounts. When the sales manager has finished entering
the sales amounts, the program will calculate the average sales amount by dividing the
value stored in the accumulator by the value stored in the counter. It then will display the
average sales amount on the screen. The sales manager will indicate that she is finished
with the program by entering a negative number as the sales amount.

Comment: You may want to read a line via [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and check what is read.

Comment: please include some example input in the question. I believe if you enter `0` the code does what you want. If you want to handle other input, please explain

Comment: I mean it can be any positive amount. if the manager enter 0 or nothing at all that program should display that it was "Invalid input".

Comment: yeah, if I enter 0 it does exactly what it intended to but what im trying to do is what if the manager did not input anything at all and just pressed enter. the cin keeps waiting until the manager enter any positive values.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> sales` returns `std::istream` object.

In C++11 and later standards , `std::istream` object will be converted to `bool`, only if we use it in `if` or `while`.

You can use : `if(cin >> sales)` to check for valid input.

References :

1. [Address and return values of cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896106/address-and-return-values-of-cin)
2. [What does cin return?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/91641/#:%7E:text=cin%20%3E%3E%20num1%20returns%20a%20reference,is%20in%20a%20good%20state.)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose getting the standard input as a `std::string` and check it for emptiness:

```
std::string sales;

// ...
getline(std::cin, sales);

if (sales.empty() || 0 == std::stod(sales)) {
  std::cout << "Invalid input!\n";
}
else {
  double salesVal = std::stod(sales);

  // and so forth
}
```

This will also make sure the entered value is a valid double value.

Comment: Why do you allow only integers as input while the original code uses `double` for input?

Comment: @MikeCAT fixed, sry.

Comment: Also note that `std::stod` doesn't fully check the input (ignore garbage suffix like `gbr` in `3gbr` and return `3` for this example).

Comment: @MikeCAT that's true, then he could add `std::any_of(sales.begin(), sales.end(), ::isdigit);`

Comment: Valid floating-point number can contain characters other than digits. (`3.14`, `5e+10`, `3E-7`, etc.) `::isdigit` cannot correctly judge them.

Comment: Also strings with only valid characters need not be valid representation of floating-point number. (example: `127.0.0.1`) You should use [`strtod()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) to do conversion and checking. (you can use `sales.c_str()` to get `const char*` for C API from `std::string`)

Comment: how about [std::strtod()](https://docs.w3cub.com/cpp/string/byte/strtof)?